# Docker access container logs from the host machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have a docker container running on a AWS EC2 instance, and would like to know if its possible to mount a directory to a container log directory so i can access the files on the host.

The service I'm running has some log files I would like to look at without accessing the container each time.

The command I tried.

```
docker run -d -v $(pwd)/datalogs:/etc/tmp/logdir -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 -p 2181:2181 --name burcon gmantmp/imagecon
```

It does create a directory on the host but it is empty. Is it possible to do this and if some where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `run` command looks fine, it will mount `/etc/tmp/logdir` from the host, so the container will be writing directly to `~/datalogs` as you want. If there's no output, you'll need to confirm the app is actually writing to`/etc/tmp/logdir`.

As a side note, if you can configure the app in your container to write `stdout` instead then you can use `docker logs` to see what's happening in the container. Then you can also use different [logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/) which gives you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: yes wrong directory `/var` not `/etc` my bad ;) thanks @Elton for quick response.